# How to configure scaladoc in eclipse juno?

Tags: scala, documentation, scala-ide, scaladoc

I'm new to scala. I've installed the nightly build since I use eclipse juno. The problem I'm facing is I do not see scaladoc when the cursor is on a class/trait and I press F2(like in java).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because it is not implemented yet. See ticket [#1000954](https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000954-include-type-information-in-f2-popup-window) and [#1000210](https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000210-scaladoc-integration-with-code-completion) for more information and future work on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. Is there any other way to refer to the doc from eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

As a poor man's alternative, the JavaDoc view works for Java elements. You can enable it from `Window/Show View` and it will show you the docs related to the element under the cursor as long as it comes from Java (even in Scala code).

Answer (score 0):

For the completeness of SO : Scaladoc is now integrated since [release 4.0.0 RC1](http://scala-ide.org/blog/release-notes-4.0.0-RC1.html) of the Scala-IDE plugin.