# How to view scala doc in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide, scaladoc

I am using Eclipse for writing Scala code.

I installed the Scala plugin in Eclipse. In the Java environment in Eclipse there are explanations available for every built in method, but for Scala, Eclipse does not show Scala doc.

What can I do to view the Scaladoc in Eclipse?

Comment: I don't think you mean "generate" scala doc, but view it? That feature's not in the released version of the scala plugin. It is in the most recently nightlies of the plugin, so presumably will be included in the next release

Comment: yes mean i want to view scala docs as there are many built in methods in scala language and as a new developer in scala i am having trouble in understanding those so i need the scala docs so what should i do until the next relase

Comment: Look at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/

Comment: The release candidate for the next version of the scala-ide is out, so presumably the actual release won't be long now

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure scaladoc in eclipse juno?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394471/how-to-configure-scaladoc-in-eclipse-juno)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the completeness of SO : Scaladoc is now integrated since [release 4.0.0 RC1](http://scala-ide.org/blog/release-notes-4.0.0-RC1.html) of the Scala-IDE plugin.

Comment: Thanks new release is awesome :)